# SqlHierarchyID casting from Datarow

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr, hierarchyid

I am trying to retrieve a SqlHierarchyID data-type in C#, from a DataRow that has been fetched from a SQL Server database. After the database call, if I write the following:

```
var id = datarow["TreeID"];
```

And then inspect the value of id using a watch in visual studio, it is holding the correct hierarchy value (and is non-null).

However, any and all of the following throw an InvalidCastException:

```
SqlHierarchyId id2 = (SqlHierarchyId) id;
SqlHierarchyId id3 = datarow.Field<SqlHierarchyId>("TreeID");
SqlHierarchyId id4 = (SqlHierarchyId)datarow["TreeID"];
```

Moreover, asking reflection for the assign-ability, of the two objects:

```
//returns false:
SqlHierarchyId id5 = new SqlHierarchyId();
return id5.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(id.GetType());
```

Moreover, trying a "soft cast" returns null:

```
SqlHierarchyId id6 = id as SqlHierarchyId;
```

- Trying everything as a SqlHierarchyId? data-type is fruitless.
- I am referencing the 32 bit assembly, and have tried compiling my solution in both 64 and 32 bit modes.
- Initializing an empty SqlHierarchyId instance and then assigning it does not help.

Thanks for any help!

-JT

**EDIT:** The assembly comes from SQL Server Express 2012 (x86) SDK directory.

Comment: What does `datarow["TreeID"].GetType()` return?

Comment: @Tim It returns"{Name = "SqlHierarchyId" FullName = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId"}"

Comment: Almost sounds like there are two different versions of the type. If you compare the Type from the DataRow with `typeof( SqlHierarchyId )` are they identical? I'm not sure what properties of the Type to check (maybe `GUID`?)

Comment: Also, are you retrieving data using a new SQL 2012 assembly, or just classes from the System.Data.Sql namespace?

Comment: Can you mark the post below as an answer if it address your needs? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I added a link to the wrong Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll. For MS SQL 2008 it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies for MS SQL 2012 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies

Comment: Basically, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version 10 should be used for SQL Server 2008. However Microsoft,SqlServer.Types edge should be used for SQL Server 2008 R2 and later (i.e 2012, 2014 etc).

Answer (score 1):

How about using

```
//convert the string back into a hierarchyid
oRow["NodeKey"] = SqlHierarchyId.Parse((string)oRow["NodeString"]);
```

I also see that you are working with a tree, so may this code project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37038/Loading-a-TreeView-using-HierarchyID) will help you

Comment: This will work if he has the "NodeString" but does not solve the original question.  In his example "TreeID" is infact a SqlHierarchyId but it looks as though the SQL server has a different version of the Types DLL then the one he has referenced in his project. I am having the same issue currently.